# Apple AppStore Sandbox renewable subscription purchase not succeeding

Tags: ios, subscription, tvos, appstore-sandbox

The issue is occurring in a setup where target Xcode scheme *StoreKit configuration* is set to **None** and on standalone ipa builds. Hence real remote AppStore sandbox is used.
[image]
Upon subscription  attempt  both on iOS & tvOS across vast version range we've identified following errors occuring:

```
Error Domain=SKErrorDomain Code=0 "Cannot connect to iTunes Store" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot connect to iTunes Store}
```

and

```
Error Domain=SKErrorDomain Code=0 "An unknown error occurred" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=An unknown error occurred, NSUnderlyingError=0x28039b6f0 {Error Domain=ASDServerErrorDomain Code=5008 "Sign in to view account information." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Sign in to view account information.}}}
```

and

```
<SKPaymentQueue: 0x280f1fa10>: Payment completed with error: Error Domain=ASDErrorDomain Code=500 "Unhandled exception" UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x2803a4720 {Error Domain=AMSErrorDomain Code=301 "Invalid Status Code" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Invalid Status Code, AMSURL=https://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZBuy.woa/wa/inAppBuy?REDACTED, AMSStatusCode=500, NSLocalizedFailureReason=The response has an invalid status code}}, NSLocalizedFailureReason=An unknown error occurred, NSLocalizedDescription=Unhandled exception}
```

We have not identified any change in our code causing this. Old builds which used to work now experience this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The culprit turned out be our Appstore Connect configuration of our subscriptions.
In the subscription config, there was a warning issued that **we do not have App Store Localization**.
[image]
The bug(?)/requirement in Apple Sandbox must be a fairly recent change introduced around July/August 2022. The very same configuration was working flawlessly for us before.

This is the App Store connect state BEFORE the Localization missing config fix was added:
[image]
and after it was added:
[image]

After adding this sandbox subscriptions started working normally immediately.

Do not forget removing the app from the device before performing any further testing.